# BBC - The Alchemists of Sound

Tags: electronic-music, vintage, innovation, sound-design

Though not strictly movie sound design as such, it's actually first and foremost about the birth of electronic (mostly cinematic) music through tremendous innovation and creativity, but it can still extremely easily be translated into our field of work as well! So I would like to share this with you guys and gals :-)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc07KzsgvqI

Answer (score 1):

I've watched this a few times; it's fantastic.

Comment: Oh yes, I absolutely love it :-)

Answer (score 1):

What I would have given to work with those people! What an amazing learning experience.

Comment: I hear you! :-)